# Обработка данных в потоке C#

Tags: c#, wpf, многопоточность

C# WPF

Не знаю как сформулировать запрос гугл, по этому пишу тут. Задача такова:
Есть метод

```
public List<object> GetObjectsFromUrl(Uri url)
```

который загружает строку с URL'а и парсит её кастомным парсером json(используя Json.Net). В общем-то задача эта довольно продолжительная и пока всё это происходит UI подвисает(естественно). Теперь вопрос: как, используя бекграунд потоки, сделать всё в этом методе?(обязательное условие чтобы именно этот метод возвращал список). Возможно я пишу какой-то бред, не судите, с Thread'ами можно сказать не работал вообще.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам надо вынести выполнение метода в фоновый поток.

Например, так:

```
List<object> objeсts = await Task.Run(() => GetObjectsFromUrl(url));
```

(Ваш метод при этом станет `async`-методом, да.)

Comment: Студия подсказывает, что async методы должны возвращать void, Task или Task<T>. Что должен вернуть мой метод?

Comment: Ну а что он возвращал до этого?

Comment: Всё, спасибо, понял какой метод станет async. А, в целом, этот способ подойдет для любой задачи которую в фоне нужно выполнить?

Comment: @eXCore: Да. Это на текущий момент рекомендуемый путь отправлять код в фоновый поток.